# ACF - Not displaying custom fields or groups on Custom post Type on edit / new admin page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, user-roles

Hi there I working on directory kind website with WordPress and AIT-FoodGuide Theme

Now I stuck... here I trying to add Custom Field with ACF But It not showing on custom post type "*items*" edit page(*backend*) of users 
[**note:But this fields visible to administrator** only]

Will you please try to find my what is the problem and what possible solution.

Custom Post type is ITEM
Not Showing to all other user e.g author editor role etc..

I Also Checked pulling ACF of normal post type.... and it works for every other user roles too..

ON TRIAL AND ERROR I  also figure out it might be it's problem of user capability... Any suggestion which one is ideal?

Comment: Did you write code to register your post type, or are you using a plugin? Is it built into the theme?

Comment: Hi it's theme  in built

Comment: it's theme inbuilt alt foodguide is name of theme

Comment: Thanks for interest i solve the problem alternate way